# How to install and configure Valgrind Memcheck?

Tags: valgrind

I've been trying to install Valgrind Memcheck on my computer but I've found nothing on the internet to help me. Can someone please walk me through the steps to install this useful tool?

I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6

I've downloaded the tar file from the official website but there wasn't much more I could do to see what comes next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, macOS 10.13 is the last one that is currently supported by the official source.

This [fork](https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos) has more up to date support, with instructions for building with `brew`.